# Node.js upgrade to 18.16.0 causing uncaughtException with [Error: Invalid argument] and no stack trace

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

After upgrading from Node.js 10.16.3 to 18.16.0, along with updating all dependencies (npm packages) of my projects, I'm encountering a vague uncaughtException error: [Error: Invalid argument]. This "error" has no stack trace, so it seems impossible for me to find where it's coming from.
This error seems to trigger when loading the webpage, but only sometimes. Even when loading the most simple page of my app, it can trigger. It seems to trigger more frequently if I've left the page "idle" for a while. When the error occurs, the page does not load, the browser keeps "loading" but the page is never served.

This makes me think the error pops up somewhere in Express js (middleware), but I can't figure out where exactly.

In order to try to get a stack trace on this error, I've tried debugging (with the integrated node.js debugger, so using "node inspect", however this didn't help at all, I still only get the same message "[Error: Invalid argument]" without trace.

How can I troubleshoot this further? I don't know which code to share, as I can't pinpoint the exact location of the error.

---

Extra information: My environment (OS) is Windows 10 22H2 build 19045.2965.
This is with the latest version of express (4.18.2).

The package.json:

```
{
  "name": "workload",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "workload app",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "author": "Mathieu",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^4.2.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.2.0",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jquery": "^3.6.3",
    "node-sspi": "^0.2.10",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.7.1",
    "tedious": "^16.1.0",
    "tedious-connection-pool2": "^2.1.0",
    "winston": "^3.8.2",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.7.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share what environment (OS) you are using, along with what version of express js you are using. package.json might help.. and also have you tried updating your libraries?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @catzilla Thank you for your reply. I added the information to my question. With libraries, do you mean the dependencies of my project? Yes, I also updated all of them.

Comment: Did you delete the node_modules folder after upgrading node?

Comment: It's possible deleting the node_modules (and then reinstalling them) fixed my problem. I also removed an unused dependency, and I can say for sure that the problem is gone now. I'll answer my own question for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to "fix" the issue eventually, although I don't know the root cause of the issue.

In my case, I removed the @popperjs/core dependency as it was no longer needed. I believe it was needed as a peer dependency for another module but this was no longer the case. After removing @popperjs/core and deleting the node_modules folder and then reinstalling the dependencies, the issue seems to be fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it happens, but something related to Node-API(a method to call native) was maybe screwed on Node 17. I solved it to downgrading to Node 14.